# what is Difference between keyword new and :(colon) symbol while creating the new instance of a class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 class i want to import one class in

Class students

```
export class students {
  public avr=123;
  constructor(a,b,c){}
}
```

class college

```
import {students} from './commonwork'
export class college{
  constructor(public abc:students){}
}
```

This way works fine.

But

when I try to create the instance of class with new keyword in College class either in constructor or any where inside the class

```
var studentinstance= new student(){}
```

I get the error as "Expected 3 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)"

Can some one please explain the difference creating the instance with new keyword and :(colon)

Comment: The colon doesn't create anything, that just specifies the *type* of the parameter. If there's a `students` in Angular's DI, it will inject it for you. When you try to `new` up a student, you indeed do not provide the arguments required. It's unclear what part of this outcome was unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public abc:students` doesn't create anything.¹ The `:students` part just assigns a type to `abc`. It doesn't create an instance of that type, it just says that if `abc` is going to refer to anything, it has to be of type `students`.

This:

```
var studentinstance= new student(){}
```

...is creating a variable (`studentinstance`) and assigning a `student` (singular) instance. The `{}` after it is not in any way connected to it, it's just an empty block following the statement which you can and should remove.

I suggest walking through some basic TypeScript tutorials.

---

¹ In the place it appears (the constructor parameter list), it *declares* `abc` as a property of the `students` instance and also as the first parameter to the constructor (and automatically sets the property from the constructor parameter). So in that sense you might say it creates a property. It doesn't create an object, however.

Answer (score 0):

`:` declares a type; it does not create an instance.

See the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html).